# Count occurrences in a list for each row and specific column in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, counter

I've been trying to use `collection.Counter` or `value_counts` in **Python 3.7** to do something like the df below, but I had no success. So far, this is an example of what I'm trying to get:

```
    IDs        Col2               Col3
0   123   [A, A, B, B, C]    {A:2, B:2, C:1}
1   456   [A, B, C, C]       {A:1, B:1, C:2}
2   789   [A, A, A, D, D]    {A:3, D:2}
```

Then I need to get for each correspondent row, the maximum value in `Col3` and, if there's a tie, show it in a new column only with the keys that tied. Something like this:

```
    IDs        Col2               Col3            Max
0   123   [A, A, B, B, C]    {A:2, B:2, C:1}   {A:2, B:2}
1   456   [A, B, C, C]       {A:1, B:1, C:2}   {C:2}
2   789   [A, A, A, D, D]    {A:3, D:2}        {A:3}
```

Comment: can you please do df.to_dict() and share the dataframe in copy-able form?

Comment: Welcome @niq13. To be improve Your question and get a precise answer You can show us how to construct the dataframe. `df = pd.DataFrame({'IDs':[123, 456, 789], 'Col12':[a, .]}) ....`
However.  You can use the groupby function of pandas DataFrame.
`df.groupby('IDs').count(), or df.groupby('IDs').max()` and then select the right column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use dict comprehension with test if value is `max`:

```
from collections import Counter

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':[123,456,789], 
                   'Col2':[list('AABBC'), list('ABCC'), list('AAADD')]})

df['Col3'] = df['Col2'].apply(Counter)
df['Max'] = df['Col3'].apply(lambda x: {k:v for k, v in x.items() if max(x.values()) == v})
```

Thank you @Keyur Potdar  for another idea use [`most_common`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common):

```
f = lambda x: {k:v for k, v in x.items() if x.most_common(1)[0][1] == v}
df['Max'] = df['Col3'].apply(f)

print (df)
   Col1             Col2                      Col3               Max
0   123  [A, A, B, B, C]  {'A': 2, 'B': 2, 'C': 1}  {'A': 2, 'B': 2}
1   456     [A, B, C, C]  {'A': 1, 'B': 1, 'C': 2}          {'C': 2}
2   789  [A, A, A, D, D]          {'A': 3, 'D': 2}          {'A': 3}
```

Comment: As the items in `Col3` are objects of `collections.Counter`, wouldn't it be better to use `x.most_common(1)[0][1] == v` instead of `max(x.values()) == v`?